# Set input value based on select input value - Issue with haml

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have haml like so:

```
.form-group
  .col-sm-3.control-label
    = f.label :trial, "Free Trial Offered"
    %span.tipsy{"data-toggle" => "tooltip", title: t("campaigns.services_form_free_trial_help")}
      = link_to content_tag(:i, "", class: 'glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign'), '#'
  .col-sm-4
    = f.select :trial, [['Yes', 'true'], ['No', 'false']], {}, class: 'selectpicker mandatory'
```

This creates the following html:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-3 control-label">
    <label for="campaign_trial">Free Trial Offered</label>
    <span class="tipsy" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Select whether or not you wish to offer a free trial with your service.">
      <a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></i></a>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <select class="selectpicker mandatory" id="campaign_trial" name="campaign[trial]" style="display: none;">
      <option value="true" selected="selected">Yes</option>
      <option value="false">No</option>
    </select>
    <div class="btn-group bootstrap-select mandatory">
      <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-id="campaign_trial" data-original-title="" title="">
        <span class="filter-option pull-left">
          Yes
        </span>&nbsp;
        <span class="caret">
        </span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" style="max-height: 89px; overflow-y: auto; min-height: 0px;">
        <li rel="0" class="selected">
          <a tabindex="0" class="">
            <span class="text">
              Yes
            </span>
            <i class="icon-ok check-mark"></i>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li rel="1" class="">
          <a tabindex="0" class="">
            <span class="text">
              No 
            </span>
            <i class="icon-ok check-mark"></i>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can no simple dropdown is created but rather a complex combination of buttons and dropdowns. I want to be able to set another input field to the value of the above however typical approaches such as jquery change handler do not work as I cannot use an id etc to identify when the dropdown changes. Can anyone advise how I could achieve this.

I was also thinking to associate two model attributes with the one dropdown so that both are set to the same value based on the one select but not sure if this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you are using `bootstrap-select`, this is the code that this library generated, not relating to HAML.

Even though it generates a lot of extras, you can still use the change event as normal:

```
$(function() {
  $('#campaign_trial').on('change', function() {
    // do things
  });
})
```